# Can't log in to database after dumpdata and loaddata

Tags: database, django, django-admin

I want to make some changes to the data on my production Django server, so I ran ./manage.py dumpdata on the production server, copied the data to my dev machine, and ran ./manage.py loaddata on the same data. However, I can't login to the admin site on localhost, even though I'm using the same password that I use to login to the production server.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `auth_user` table to see if your username is there. If it is, then go into the shell and change your password.

**Edit:**
Just realized that you can actually go in your shell and check if the current password is what you think it is by using `check_password`:

```
>> user = User.objects.get(pk=[insert_id_here])
>> user.check_password('password')
>> True
```

Comment: Thanks, my user wasn't there for some reason.